# Short story about a rebellious mage whose mother reverts him to childhood

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I think it was a comedic fantasy short story. The mage grows up and heads off to challenge a more powerful mage, who turns out to be his mother. After the battle, she reverses his age until he is a baby, then sets about raising him again.

He may have been a necromancer.

Comment: Off to a good start, but if you haven't already, can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) and see if you can edit in any more details?

Comment: Welcome to SFF! Can you take a look at [this guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337) and [edit] in anymore details you may remember. For example, when did you read this?

Answer (score 6):

I think this is one of the stories in *[Third Time Lucky; and other Stories of the Most Powerful Wizard in the World](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/24965354-third-time-lucky)* by Tanya Huff. Possibly the title story, as it is mentioned that she has reverted and re-raised him before.The wizard, Magdalene, is also very lazy, and likes spending most of her time sunbathing. It makes a change to have a wizard who doesn't want to rule the world!

Comment: Yes this sounds very like the story. I have the anthology and the story is a close match. I can edit in supporting quotes if you like.